# Web Drive Selenium Exception Error "Server Not Found" or like that

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm Creating an automation application by python. It should Signup for Instagram.
I'm not a professional guy in python. I need a mechanism to control web page error . in my situation , some times web page is not loaded and it says "server not found" or when the connection is not stable page not loaded for dns problem and automation fails & errors appear.
as i know , i must use Try{} catch{}. but i don't know how and what syntax i should use. 
is it any source and examples ? i can't find that.
Python2.7

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import names
import time
import random
import string
import bs4
import re
#import outlook
import urllib2
from createalias import create_alias
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.common.exceptions


def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


def checkname():
        line = names.get_full_name(gender='male')
        line=line.replace(" ","")
        random.seed()
        num=random.randint(50,200)
        line=line+str(num)
        driver.get("http://www.instagram.com/"+line)
        try:
             if "Page Not Found" in driver.title:
                 return line
        except WebDriverException:
                return 0

profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.cache.disk.enable', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.cache.memory.enable', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.cache.offline.enable', False)
profile.set_preference('network.cookie.cookieBehavior', 2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

line=""
#f=open(r'C:\Users\11\Desktop\emailes.txt','r')
for x in range(5, 10):
        username=checkname()
        if username !=0:
                        password=id_generator()
                        #email=f.readline().strip()
                        userdomain="abobakbaghdadi"+str(x)+"@gmail.com"
                        f2=open(r'C:\Users\11\Desktop\info.txt','a')
                        f2.write(str(userdomain) + "," + str(username) + "," + str(password))
                        f2.write("\n")
                        f2.close()
                        driver.get("http://www.instagram.com")
                        assert "Instagram" in driver.title
                        time.sleep(4)
                        elem=driver.find_element_by_name("emailOrPhone")
                        elem.clear
                        time.sleep(3)
                        elem.send_keys(userdomain)
                        elem=driver.find_element_by_name("fullName")
                        elem.clear
                        time.sleep(2)
                        elem.send_keys(username)
                        elem=driver.find_element_by_name("username")
                        elem.clear
                        elem.send_keys(username)
                        elem=driver.find_element_by_name("password")
                        elem.clear
                        elem.send_keys(password)
                        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
                        #flag=1
        else:
                x=x-1
```

one of that errors:

```
WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=http%3A//www.instagram.com/AndrewLitzenberg86&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=We%20can%E2%80%99t%20connect%20to%20the%20server%20at%20www.instagram.com.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try/catch block in python is :

```
try:
    connect()
except Exception:
    print('Error while connecting')
```

Comment: thank you buddy, i want to control the error, for example during the sign up internet disconnected, the page refresh again, but interrupt it. or i want to return 0 and do not interrupt, but that error i mentioned is appear.  i entered the whole code and edited the post, see it again.

Comment: try:
                "Page Not Found" in driver.title
                return line
        except WebDriverException:
                return 0
not worked

Comment: Try is not a if block : you should do `if "page not found" in driver.title.lower()`

Comment: yes you right but it has problem as before . i added "if" in try block, but when i shutdown the internet network , the error comes up again  : WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=http%3A//www.instagram.com/AndrewLitzenberg86&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=We%20can%E2%80%99t%20connect%20to%20the%20server%20at%20www.instagram.com

Comment: i want it can refresh the page until it can be loaded completely.

Comment: `while 'thing you want' not in driver.page_source: driver.refresh()`